# Is it possible to change BO class name different from table name?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

I am using struts, now I have a question:
Is it possible the name of BO class be different from table name in database?
when I change the name, it makes error

Comment: Struts doesn't do persistence, what persistence layer are you using?

Comment: I don't know form when Struts BO have started interacting with Data Base. Please check your OR Mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check a table name associated with your object if you use annotations.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "yourtablename")
public class YourClass {...}
```

Comment: I use Hibernate 3 in persistence layer. I used the @Table name in my BO class. But I am not sure that the class name makes the error or not.

Comment: If you use @Table with a specific table name, it does not matter how you call your class name otherwise class name should match database table.